# Are the bookseries and authordate options compatible in biblatex-chicago package?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

The following code throws an error, "`Package keyval Error: bookseries undefined. \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bookseries=false}`":

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bookseries=false}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

But if I don't use authordate, there's no error message. On the surface, there's no obvious reason why `bookseries` should not apply with the author-date format. So am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

In the [`biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) on p. 61 we find

> According to the Manual (14.128), the `series` field in book-like entries “may be  omitted to save space (especially in a footnote).”

You will find that the option only applies to citations (in-text or footnotes) with the `note` style. The `series` will always appear in the bibliography regardless of the setting.

Thus it indeed does not make much sense to have the option in the author-date styles. You will probably not have (many) full citations in your document with that style and the bibliography, where the `series` could appear is unaffected by the option.

But we can make that option apply to the bibliography in `authordate`

```
\providetoggle{cms@bookseries}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{bookseries}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cms@bookseries}{#1}}%

\DeclareEntryOption{bookseries}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cms@bookseries}{#1}}%

\renewbibmacro*{ser+num}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@bookseries}%
  {\printfield{series}%
    \printfield[sernum]{number}}%
  {}}%
```

Note: If you are using the `notes` style you will only need the very last `\renewbibmacro`, you can drop the rest. Then the `bookseries` option will apply to the bibliography as well.

Remember to put the code before you actually execute the bibliography option.

In full

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\providetoggle{cms@bookseries}
\DeclareBibliographyOption{bookseries}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cms@bookseries}{#1}}%

\DeclareEntryOption{bookseries}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cms@bookseries}{#1}}%

\newbibmacro*{ser+num}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@bookseries}%
  {\printfield{series}%
    \printfield[sernum]{number}}%
  {}}%

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{bookseries=false}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{coleridge}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```